# REST Console Extension in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox-addon

I am using REST Console.

I have to add multiple attachment with different parameter key. But I am not able to find option for this.

Is there is any other Extension available?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have a couple other options:

### Chrome:

[Postman - REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm)

[Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)

### Firefox:

[RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/restclient/)

[REST Easy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rest-easy/) (thanks to Nathan)

See if some of them meet your needs

Comment: You might want to add [REST Easy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rest-easy/) to your list for Firefox. (Disclaimer: I am the lead developer for the add-on.)

Comment: @NathanOsman, thank you so much. RESTEasy looks better than RESTClient. For me of course.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely suggest DHC for chrome. For quite some time now I am using it on daily basis and I can say it works just fine and have features like saving entire requests under specific project -> method.

Here's demo: https://www.sprintapi.com/dhcs.html
Here's google chrome store link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-resthttp-api-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm?hl=en

If you just search for REST API console within google store you'll find many more.

All the best